# Where is .gitignore_global saved on OS X?

Tags: git, macos, gitignore

I have created a `.gitignore_global` file by running

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

However, I can't find the file in question in my file system? Where was it saved?

Comment: When I open terminal, it opens in my user directory. When I type ls -al, it doesn't show the .gitignore_global file. It does show the .gitconfig file

Comment: Hm... I suppose I only set the config file without creating the .gitignore_global file itself...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I have created a `.gitignore_global` file using the command [...]

The command

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global
```

does *not* create any file. In other words, if `~/.gitignore_global` did not exist beforehand, running that command does not create it.

The semantics of that command are

> Set the path of the *user-level* (because of the `--global` flag) Git ignore file to `~/.gitignore_global`.

In terms of implementation, that command adds the following entry

```
excludesfile = ~/.gitignore_global
```

under the `core` section of your `~/.gitconfig` file, which is the default path for the *user-level* config file. See [this section of the Pro Git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Configuration) for more details about the three levels (system, user, repository) of Git configuration files.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that.

Answer (score 27):

#### In terminal: (macOS Catalina)

1. `touch ~/.gitignore_global`
2. `open .gitignore_global` add: `.DS_Store`
3. `git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore_global`

And you're done

Comment: Doesn't answer OPs question exactly, but it answers the question everyone else came here for

Answer (score 12):

You can find the file location by running this command in Terminal:

```
git config --get core.excludesfile
```

Comment: I run `git config --get core.excludesfile` and get `--global`. This is the reason why the global ignore does not work? with `git config --list --global` I get `core.excludesfile=~/.gitignore`